# how to use webSocket in angular 6

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs, angular6, stompjs

i need to use webSocket to make a communication between spring and angular 6 (notification), i tried to import stompjs, sockJs-client or even angular2-websocket but nothing works, could you help me ? thank you.

Comment: angular2-websocket works fine with Angular 6.  What has been your particular problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the documentation provided by Spring using sockJS and stomp. 
But with angular 6 not able to import the Stomp and SockJS.
Finally found a way to make the socket working with angular 6 stomp and spring.
This works with well for me with angular 6.
Please go through this.
http://newjavafaqs.blogspot.com/2018/06/web-socket-using-spring-and-stomp.html

Comment: The article has no filenames or source files, just a bunch of code sections.. couldn't follow and make it work... can you help? which one is "wsdata.model.ts" is the one i couldent resolve.. and the rest are guesses too until i can make this to work.